# API Platform validation errors versus ORM exceptions

Tags: api-platform.com

Within the API Platform, how can thrown exceptions be replaced with validation errors? According to [this issue](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/788), it appears to be an unsolved question.

As a test, create an entity with a single, integer property. Adding the `@Assert\Positive` annotation will validate that the value is a positive integer.

Trying to create a record with various values below produces the subsequent response.

First an error message, as expected, when passing a negative value:

`{ "myInt": -1 }`

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/ConstraintViolationList",
  "@type": "ConstraintViolationList",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "myInt: This value should be positive.",
  "violations": [
    {
      "propertyPath": "myInt",
      "message": "This value should be positive."
    }
  ]
}
```

Second, a thrown exception, not what is expected, when passing in a string:

`{ "myInt": "A" }`

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/Error",
  "@type": "hydra:Error",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "The type of the \"myInt\" attribute must be \"int\", \"string\" given.",
  "trace": [
    ... 771 lines of stack trace ...
  ]
}
```

Attempting a fix based on previous research into the issue (adding `denormalizationContext={"disable_type_enforcement"=true}` to @ApiResource) simply results in a different thrown exception.

If this is because of the ORM type checking, it seems to mean that you can either generate entities with ORM annotations for migrations, or you must remove the ORM annotations and manually create migrations so that you can rely only on validation constraints to produce proper errors.

Note that this is not just for integers. Any value that does not meet the criteria defined in the ORM annotation throws an exception rather than a validation error.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Note that removing ORM annotations or solely relying on client-side validation should not be valid solutions.

Comment: After lots of attempts, I figured out this is coming from the setter method. Because that method is type hinted to accept an integer, anything else will throw an exception. It seems the only way around this is to remove the type hinting.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea. At first, You have to understand serialization process of api-platform https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/. If You will do it, then You have to decorate serializer of Your entity (or even field in the entity, for example date field). Example is in https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/340. At last in decorated serializer, before denormalization You have to validate the desired field and throw ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Validator\Exception\ValidationException. That's it. For me it was needed 1 day to find this out.